# JavaFX TreeView restore Scroll State

Tags: java, javafx, scrollbar, javafx-8

I want to save current scroll state of a TreeView component and restore that state any time.

I tried many things to get scroll position and set it back but couldn't do it in any way.

The key point here is that we need to save min,max,value,unitInc,blockInc values and restore these values when needed. Only value or only min and max is not enough to restore correctly.

**Update**

**Listen vertical value changes and store scroll state**

```
Set<Node> nodes = this.treeView.lookupAll(".scroll-bar");
for (Node node : nodes) {
    ScrollBar scrollBar = getScrollBar(node);
    if (scrollBar.getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
        scrollBar.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            double value = newValue.doubleValue();
            if (value > 0) {
                scrollState.setMin(scrollBar.getMin());
                scrollState.setMax(scrollBar.getMax());
                scrollState.setUnitIncrement(scrollBar.getUnitIncrement());
                scrollState.setBlockIncrement(scrollBar.getBlockIncrement());
                scrollState.setVerticalValue(value);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Store scroll state here also**

```
private ScrollBar getScrollBar(Node node) {
    ScrollBar scrollBar = (ScrollBar) node;
    if (Objects.nonNull(scrollBar)) {
        scrollState.setMin(scrollBar.getMin());
        scrollState.setMax(scrollBar.getMax());
        scrollState.setUnitIncrement(scrollBar.getUnitIncrement());
        scrollState.setBlockIncrement(scrollBar.getBlockIncrement());
    }

    return scrollBar;
}
```

**Restore stored scroll state**

```
threadService.schedule(() -> { // run after some ms, it is important
    threadService.runActionLater(() -> { // run in ui thread

        Set<Node> nodes = this.treeView.lookupAll(".scroll-bar");
        for (Node node : nodes) {
            ScrollBar scrollBar = getScrollBar(node);
            if (scrollBar.getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
                double verticalValue = scrollState.getVerticalValue();
                if (verticalValue > 0) {
                    scrollBar.setMin(scrollState.getMin());
                    scrollBar.setMax(scrollState.getMax());
                    scrollBar.setUnitIncrement(scrollState.getUnitIncrement());
                    scrollBar.setBlockIncrement(scrollState.getBlockIncrement());
                    scrollBar.setValue(verticalValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }, true);
}, 50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I have updated my answer with your finding about block and unitIncrement to have the answer absolutely complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just **scroll to an index** in the `TreeView`, then you can use the [scrollTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html#scrollTo-int-) method (e.g. you save the selected index, then you sroll to this index later):

```
tree.scrollTo(5);
```

In the case if you actually want to **store and then restore the positions** of the `ScrollBar`s, you can use the [lookupAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookupAll-java.lang.String-) method of `Node` class to look for `.scroll-bar` style then to case it to `ScrollBar` object which has a [minProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollBar.html#minProperty), [maxProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollBar.html#maxProperty) and [valueProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollBar.html#valueProperty) to store.

**Update:**

Based on OP's finding, the [unitIncrementProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollBar.html#unitIncrementProperty) and the [blockIncrementProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollBar.html#blockIncrementProperty) of the `ScrollBar` also should be stored and restored to properly support the operation.

**Example**

In the example I have filled a `TreeView` with some dummy data. It contains a `Button` to save the position of the horizontal and the vertical `ScrollBar` into a member object, that able to store the min, max, value, blockIncrement and unitIncrement values of the position. It also has a `Button` to restore the last saved scrollbar-positions.

```
public class TreeViewSample extends Application {

    // Members to store the horizontal and vertical positions
    private ScrollBarState hScrollBarState = null;
    private ScrollBarState vScrollBarState = null;

    TreeView<String> tree;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tree View Sample with scrollbars");

        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<String>("Items");
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
            TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<String>("Long long long long long long long Item" + i);
            rootItem.getChildren().add(item);
        }

        tree = new TreeView<String>(rootItem);
        VBox root = new VBox();


        Button buttonSave = new Button("Save ScrollBars!");
        buttonSave.setOnAction((event) -> {
            // On save get the scrollbars and update the members (if the scrollbar is present)
            ScrollBar bar = getScrollBar(tree, Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
            if (bar != null)
                hScrollBarState = new ScrollBarState(bar.getMin(), bar.getMax(), bar.getValue(), bar.getBlockIncrement(), bar.getUnitIncrement());

            bar = getScrollBar(tree, Orientation.VERTICAL);

            if (bar != null)
                vScrollBarState = new ScrollBarState(bar.getMin(), bar.getMax(), bar.getValue(), bar.getBlockIncrement(), bar.getUnitIncrement());

        });

        Button buttonRestore = new Button("Restore ScrollBars!");
        buttonRestore.setOnAction((event) -> {

            restoreScrollBarPositions(getScrollBar(tree, Orientation.HORIZONTAL), hScrollBarState);
            restoreScrollBarPositions(getScrollBar(tree, Orientation.VERTICAL), vScrollBarState);
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(tree, buttonSave, buttonRestore);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private ScrollBar getScrollBar(TreeView<?> tree, Orientation orientation) {
        // Get the ScrollBar with the given Orientation using lookupAll
        for (Node n : tree.lookupAll(".scroll-bar")) {
            if (n instanceof ScrollBar) {
                ScrollBar bar = (ScrollBar) n;

                if (bar.getOrientation().equals(orientation))
                    return bar;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void restoreScrollBarPositions(ScrollBar bar, ScrollBarState state) {
        // Set back the position values if they present
        if (bar != null && state != null) {
            bar.setMin(state.min);
            bar.setMax(state.max);
            bar.setValue(state.value);
            bar.setUnitIncrement(state.unitIncrement);
            bar.setBlockIncrement(state.blockIncrement);
        }
    }

    // Simple class to store the position values
    class ScrollBarState {
        double min;
        double max;
        double value;
        double blockIncrement;
        double unitIncrement;

        ScrollBarState(double min, double max, double value, double blockInc, double unitInc) {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
            this.value = value;
            this.blockIncrement = blockInc;
            this.unitIncrement = unitInc;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @DVarga. I used like that, but sometimes it doesn't update scrollbar even if it sets the new value. There seems a stability issue.

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful for someone. I created a friendlier state object based on DVarga's solution. This one is using a TextArea.

```
public class ScrollBarState
{
  private final TextArea textArea;
  private final Orientation orientation;
  private ScrollBar scrollBar;

  private double min;
  private double max;
  private double value;
  private double blockIncrement;
  private double unitIncrement;

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
  // constructor
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

  public ScrollBarState (TextArea textArea, Orientation orientation)
  {
    this.textArea = textArea;
    this.orientation = orientation;
  }

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
  // reset
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

  public void reset ()
  {
    scrollBar = null;
  }

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
  // save
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

  public void save ()
  {
    if (scrollBar == null && !setScrollBar ())
      return;

    this.min = scrollBar.getMin ();
    this.max = scrollBar.getMax ();
    this.value = scrollBar.getValue ();
    this.blockIncrement = scrollBar.getBlockIncrement ();
    this.unitIncrement = scrollBar.getUnitIncrement ();
  }

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
  // restore
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

  public void restore ()
  {
    if (scrollBar == null)
      return;

    scrollBar.setMin (min);
    scrollBar.setMax (max);
    scrollBar.setValue (value);
    scrollBar.setUnitIncrement (unitIncrement);
    scrollBar.setBlockIncrement (blockIncrement);
  }

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
  // setScrollBar
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

  private boolean setScrollBar ()
  {
    for (Node node : textArea.lookupAll (".scroll-bar"))
      if (node instanceof ScrollBar
          && ((ScrollBar) node).getOrientation ().equals (orientation))
      {
        scrollBar = (ScrollBar) node;
        return true;
      }
    return false;
  }
}
```